# Is the real rank of a matrix always larger than its binary rank?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be an $n \times n$ matrix, all of whose entries are either 0 or 1. $A$ can be viewed as a matrix over $\mathbb{F}_2$ or as a matrix over $\mathbb{R}$. Is there any relationship between the real rank (rank over $\mathbb{R}$) and the binary rank (rank over $\mathbb{F}_2$) of $A$?

(The context of this question comes from communication complexity, where one can bound the communication complexity of boolean functions by the ranks of their associated matrices. I've heard it claimed that the real rank is always at least as large as the binary rank, but haven't been able to find a source.)

Comment: What about the identity matrix? Does it not have the same rank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is well-known that the rank of an $n \times m$-matrix $A$ is the maximal integer $k$ such that $A$ has a $k \times k$-submatrix $A'$ (obtained from´$A$ by deleting $(n-k)$ rows and $(m-k)$ columns) with $\det A' \ne 0$.

For any $k \times k$-matrix $B$ with entries $0$ or $1$ we clearly have $\det_{{\mathbb F}_2} B = \det_{\mathbb R} B \mod 2$ (recall the formula $\det B = \sum_{\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_n}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^kb_{i\sigma(i)}$). Thus, if  $det_{{\mathbb F}_2} B \ne 0$, then also $\det_{\mathbb R} B \ne 0$.

This shows that $\text{rank}_{{\mathbb F}_2} A \le \text{rank}_{\mathbb R} A$. The identity matrix shows that $=$ is possible.

Answer (score 2):

If by "larger", you mean "not less than", then yes, it's true.  Consider reducing the real matrix to row-echelon form.  Any rows that end up being $0$ are also $0\pmod{2}$, but there may be additional, nonzero rows that are $0\pmod{2}$.